# how can I generate one letter with birthday?

Tags: java

I'm new to java, and my teacher asked for Java code about shopping.

This is the requirement for the ID:

> The customer should enter the ID in the following format: `xddmmyyyy`.
>
> - ddmmyyyy represents the date of birth, x can be either a, A, b, or B.
> - If the customer is above 70 years old (calculate age using the year of birth only)
> - and if the customer’s ID starts with a or A, they are entitled to a 15% discount

I did this one but users should first enter a letter and then enter their birthday — which is wrong .

How can I generate something like `xddmmyyy` in one scanner?

```
System.out.println("Enter letter ");
y = scanner.nextLine();

try {
    if (y.equalsIgnoreCase("a") || y.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your ID as YYYY-MM-DD: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(input);

        System.out.println("your ID is :" + y + getAge(dob));
    }
}
```

#### Method: getAge

```
// Returns age given the date of birth
public static int getAge(LocalDate dob) {
    LocalDate curDate = LocalDate.now();
    return Period.between(dob, curDate).getYears();
}
```

Actually, my output for this: `B30`. Can someone help me with that? The output should be like this example:

> your ID is : B10021987

Comment: You have `Please enter your ID as YYYY-MM-DD` while you expect `xddmmyyyy`.... !?

Comment: @RobinTopper yes , because i cant find another solution to and letter with birth day

Answer (score 0):

The task is:

> The customer should enter the ID in the following format: `xddmmyyyy`

This means to ask for ID, all 9 characters, then validate that:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your ID as xddmmyyyy: ");
String id = scanner.nextLine();
// Validate here
```

Validation means:

- Length must be 9.
- First character must be `a`, `A`, `b`, or `B`. Use `charAt(0)` to get first character.
- Other 8 characters must be a date. Use `substring()` to get the 8 characters, then use `DateTimeFormatter` with `LocalDate.parse()` to both validate it and get birthday as a `LocalDate`.

Next you need to calculate age:

> Calculate age **using the year of birth only**

Your code is using full date, not year only. Instead, do this:

```
int age = Year.now().getValue() - birthDate.getYear();
```

I'll leave the rest of the coding up to you, so you can learn to do it.

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter your ID as xddmmyyyy: ");
  String id = scanner.nextLine();

  char result = id.charAt(0);

  System.out.print("Yor ID is :");

  System.out.println(result + id.substring(1));
  
  
  //String str = "1986-04-08 12:30";
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
  LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(id, formatter);
  String id1 = scanner.nextLine();

Comment: Why did you specify pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` when that is not the format of the entered date-only value? What is purpose of `id1`, when you already have everything you need?

Comment: i font this solution in the internet but did not work with me .

Comment: LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(id);

  System.out.println("your ID is :" + result + id.substring(1) + getAge(dob));